# Importing a .xlsx file using Laravel Excel errors "Allowed memory size exhausted"

Tags: excel, laravel

I am using Laravel Excel to import xlsx files into a Laravel project. So far everything is working perfectly, until this error that I can't figure out why is happening.

I am importing the file via a Job:

```
class ProcessImportedTable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $path;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Excel::import(new ProductsImport, public_path($this->path));

        return 'Done!';
    }
}
```

But when the queue is working I am hitting the following error:

```
[2022-05-04 11:16:41][581] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessImportedTable

 Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError

 Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 50345048 bytes)

 at vendor/league/commonmark/src/Util/RegexHelper.php:86

     82▕      */
     83▕     public static function matchAt(string $regex, string $string, int $offset = 0): ?int
     84▕     {
     85▕         $matches = [];
  ➜  86▕         $string = \mb_substr($string, $offset, null, 'utf-8');
     87▕         if (!\preg_match($regex, $string, $matches, \PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
     88▕             return null;
     89▕         }
     90▕
```

No matter what I do I can't even reach the ProductsImport class where I am working with the parsed excel data. The job fails in the middle.

When I had success with the previous files the queue goes like this:

```
[2022-05-04 11:16:08][577] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessImportedTable
[2022-05-04 11:16:08][577] Processed:  App\Jobs\ProcessImportedTable
[2022-05-04 11:16:08][578] Processing: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\QueueImport
[2022-05-04 11:16:08][578] Processed:  Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\QueueImport
[2022-05-04 11:16:08][579] Processing: Maatwebsite\Excel\Jobs\ReadChunk
...
```

**EDIT**:

I have made some changes in order to see the error better. I did this:

```
public function handle()
    {
        try {
            Excel::import(new ProductsImport, public_path($this->path));
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            $exception = $e->getMessage();

            Log::error($exception);
        }

        return 'Done!';
    }
```

And now the error log starts with the following:

```
[2022-05-04 12:05:24] local.ERROR: Packets out of order. Expected 3 received 2. Packet size=60 (SQL: insert into `jobs` (`queue`, `attempts`, `reserved_at`, `available_at`, `created_at`, `payload`) values (default, 0, ?, 1651655124, 1651655124, {"uuid":"f3e3dcb3-c4fb-4d0e-b508-aa29de211e5f","displayName":"Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Jobs\\QueueImport","job":"Illuminate\\Queue\\CallQueuedHandler@call","maxTries":null,"maxExceptions":null,"backoff":null,"timeout":null,"retryUntil":null,"data":{"commandName":"Maatwebsite\\Excel\\Jobs\\QueueImport" ...
```

Comment: What is your `memory_limit` value set to in your `php.ini` file and have you tried increasing that (if it is small)?

Comment: Yes I have tried to increase it, I also just tested if I set `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1')` and what I got is `[2022-05-04 11:44:59][583] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessImportedTable [1]    81580 killed     php artisan queue:work`

Comment: Have you looked over the [chunking imports](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/chunk-reading.html) documentation?

Comment: I am using verison 3.1 and didn't find chunk imports there. Is this still available in the latest version? I am using chunks but only after the file is processed, and at the moment the error occurs before I can reach the ProductsImport class.

Comment: I've updated the link in my previous comment for `3.1`. I didn't notice it was `2.1`. /facepalm

Comment: Yeah I am using the chunks linked in the `3.1` but the error occurs during the processing of the file and the chunks come after the file is processed and ready to work with.

Comment: Your code is somehow causing a Markdown library to fail while allocating 50MB of memory. I would double check where/why you are using Markdown to ensure you don't have any bugs there.